# Detecting a short url using Python

Tags: python, pandas, url

Sorry if this has been addressed previously, but I couldn't find any prior solutions to this. I'm using Pandas to extract domains from URLs and count the results. Is there a way to assign a boolean value depending on whether or not URLs are short links such as bit.ly and goo.gl? Can urllib.urlopen be used to verify that a link is a short link?

Here's pseudo-Python that hopefully illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
if urllib.urlopen(df['url']) != df['url']:
    df['short_url'] = True
else:
    df['short_url'] = False
```

Comment: But here you assign a boolean to a **column**?

Comment: Right - I'll revise the question to clarify

Comment: You'll probably need to hit the url and see if you get a 3xx status. Even then I dont think you could be certain it was a shortened url. Other option perhaps maintain a list of known url shortening services.

Comment: Okay, thanks Paul. Sounds like this might be tough to implement comprehensively.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially a "short url" is a facade url that just redirects to a final url. So you can use the getUrl method from urllib2.

> geturl() — return the URL of the resource retrieved, commonly used to
>   determine if a redirect was followed

```
import urllib2
original_url = 'http://someshorturl/5b2su2'
response = urllib2.urlopen(original_url)
# final_url != original_url if redirected
final_url = response.geturl() 
# response_code will be 302 for redirects
response_code = response.getcode()

if response_code == 302:
    # redirected so this may a short url
else:
    # this is not a short url
```

Of course there is a flaw with this because any url can be a redirect... not just short urls from a url shortening service (like goo.gl or tinyrl).

If you really need to be 100% sure then you might need to do a regex test of the url against known url shortening service domains. You may need to do a combination of things to meet your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, Calvin. Good point - I didn't take into account that other types of links can redirect. Still, this gives me something to work with.